# Saving reference to a mongoose document, after findOneAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, sockets, mongoose

I feel like I'm encountering something completely simple, yet can not figure it out, will be glad, if you can help me.

I'm using `mongoose` + `socket.io` as CRUD between client and server. As I'm using sockets, there is a private scope individual for each client's socket, in which, for future use without making db find calls, I would like to store a reference of mongoose document, that I once found for this user.

One client is creanting a `Room`:

```
var currentroom;

client.on('roomcreate', function (data) {       
   currentroom = new Room({
      Roomid: id,
      UsersMeta: [UserMeta],
      ///other stuff///
      })
    currentroom.save(function (err, room) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log('success');
    });
});
```

Then, whenewer I want, on another creator's call I can just simply

```
currentroom.Roomnaid = data;
curretroom.save()
```

And it's working fine, the problem is - I do not understand how I can get the same reference on not creating, but `Room` search, for the moment i'm using this for search:

```
 Room.findOneAndUpdate({ Roomid: roomid }, { $push: { UsersMeta: UserMeta}}, { new: false }, function (err, room) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log('room output:');        
    console.log(room);
    client.emit('others', room);
 })
```

The thing is, that in one call I want to:
1: find a doc in db,
3: send it to user (in pre-updated state),
4: update found document,
2: save a reference (of the current updated doc)

With `findOneAndUpdate` I can do all, but not saving a current reference.
So, how I need to approach it then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this;

```
Room.findOne({ Roomid: roomid }, function (err, oldRoom) {
    //make changes to oldRoom
    //then save it like this
    oldRoom.save(function(err,newRoom) {
      //newRoom is updated document
      //now you have reference to both old and new docs
    });
 })
```

Comment: Thx for another usefull reply, Safi.
But isn't oldRoom will be a reference to updated room after saving (which is fine as I can send old `oldroom` before saving obviously). In my original example after `currentroom.Roomnaid = data;` `currentroom.save()` console.log(currentroom) showed that it is updated. Or is it just `currentroom.save()` returning updated doc if you don't pass response handling function in `save()`?

Comment: oh wait, i WAS paasing a response handling function in fact, `currentroom` was changed anyway

Comment: oldRoom and newRoom should be different, and if that still doesn't work for you, you can do findAndUpdate instead of save, within findOne

Comment: Well tested this, you need to edit in your answer `function(newRoom)` to `function(err, newRoom)` or it will return null in mongoose.
I pushed to `oldRoom` and then saved, in save callback i logged `oldRoom` and `newRoom`, they are both updated and identical. Again maybe specific for mongoose and you are reffering to mongodb behavior?
everything is working now with this findOne construction, therefore thank you for your answer. Can you edit it, and i will accept.

Comment: Ah now im a bit stuck with idea to add here a populate, if i need to populate room before sending to user and save unpopulated changed version to db and to variable at the same time, i cant imagine how to do this, cos fact of population will made it impossible to save\update unpopulated array.  Got any ideas?

Comment: Made another question regarding my last comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727079/mongoose-node-js-how-to-find-populate-do-stuff-depopulate-and-update

Answer (score 0):

In the end of the road i found out that i was trying to make it wrong. The idea of storing reference (instance) of doc, accessed by different users is obviously bad, as it leads to data conflicts between those instances. Also, approach with separate find and save can cause racing conditions and conflics as being non atomic operation, its far better to use findOneAnd*** to make mongoose\mongoDB handle db requests querieng by itself and make sure that no conflicts will occure.